# Instagram User Tracking

Tags: instagram

I am fetching user likes on a particular photo and saving usernames on DB, works fine.

But I want to know if a user changed there username, how I can track this user is one who liked my photo, because username saved on DB will be not same after user changed username.

How I can track this?. I am working on project so its a client requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Save `user_id` instead of `usernames`, user_id will not change when username is changed.